# SQL simple registration - all time exception

Tags: asp.net, sql, exception, registration

i have problem with registration in ASP.NET.

When i try to add new user to table in sql i catch exception. No idea what is wrong, in my opinion code is correct.

Look at this:

```
public partial class Registeration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RejConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open(); 
            string cmdStr="Select count(*) from Registration where UserName='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand userExist = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(userExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            con.Close();
            if (temp == 1) 
            {
                Response.Write("Already exist.<br /> Change another nickname.");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Wyślij_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RejConnectionString"].ConnectionString);//połączenie z bazą
        con.Open();
        string insCmd = "Insert into Registration (UserName, Password, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) values (@UserName, @Password, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @Country)";
        SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName,", TextBoxUN.Text);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBoxPass.Text);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", TextBoxEA.Text);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", TextBoxFN.Text);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());

        try
        {
            insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("/Account/Login.aspx");
        }

        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Response.Write("<b>STH bad happened :( Try again</b>");
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, don't you think it would be helpful if you also showed the exception messages?

Comment: More importantly, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: You also need to close your `SqlConnection`

Comment: You may also want to set an authentication cookie before forwarding them to account page.

Answer (score 1):

well 
1. DO NOT DO REDIRECTs inside of TRY!!!!  Response.Redirect("/Account/Login.aspx"); NO NO!!
2. if you do with finally DO THE CLOSE connection there

I will redo this try Open connection to be inside as well

Comment: Can you give some code example, becouse i'm not sure what do you mean ?